# Method of assigning a number to the number of attempts that have appeared from it, with the first attempt appearing as number 1

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

I want to assign the first trial that appears as number 1 and the number of trials that appear from there as elements of the list, plus a number.

At first, The following listA consisting of {a, b}. In practice, {a, b} is like an address determined by a random integer.

For example, there is listA.

```
listA = {{{1, 3}, {1, 1}, {3, 3}, {3, 1}},
         {{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}},
         {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}},
         {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}, 
         {{3, 3}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}}};
```

and listA is represented in a table as follows.

[image]

Next, I want to create a newlistA made up of {{a,b},c}.

```
templistA = {{{{1, 3},c}, {{1, 1},c}, {{3, 3},c}, {{3, 1},c}}, 
             {{{1, 3},c}, {{1, 2},c}, {{2, 1},c}, {{2, 3},c}}, 
             {{{3, 1},c}, {{3, 2},c}, {{1, 1},c}, {{1, 2},c}}, 
             {{{2, 2},c}, {{2, 3},c}, {{3, 1},c}, {{3, 3},c}}, 
             {{{3, 3},c}, {{3, 2},c}, {{2, 3},c}, {{2, 1},c}}};
```

The first occurrence of {a, b} is numbered as trial number 1. I want to number the next occurrence of {a, b} by counting from the number of trials in which it first appeared. And I want to create newlistA.

So, newlistA is represented in a table as follows.

[image]

I hope newlistA will be as follows.

```
  newlistA ={{{{1, 3},1}, {{1, 1},1}, {{3, 3},1}, {{3, 1},1}}, 
               {{{1, 3},2}, {{1, 2},1}, {{2, 1},1}, {{2, 3},1}}, 
               {{{3, 1},3}, {{3, 2},1}, {{1, 1},3}, {{1, 2},2}}, 
               {{{2, 2},1}, {{2, 3},3}, {{3, 1},4}, {{3, 3},4}}, 
               {{{3, 3},5}, {{3, 2},3}, {{2, 3},4}, {{2, 1},4}}};
```

Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: Imagine you needed to tell me step by step how to find each `c` and then I must correctly do this alone without asking more questions. Please tell me exactly the steps I must do and the information I must use to do this for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
With[
  {homeRows = # -> First[FirstPosition[listA, #]] & /@ Union @@ listA},
  MapIndexed[{#1, 1 + #2[[1]] - Lookup[homeRows, Key[#1]]} &, listA, {-2}]]
```